# Error with headless chrome driver unable to click an anchor element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I'm trying to test my pagination feature with rspec, capybara, selenium, and chrome headless driver. I keep running into this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Paginations user clicks on next button
     Failure/Error: click_link('next page')
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError:
       element click intercepted: Element <a class="paginator-btn" href="/articles?page=2&amp;items_limit=10" style="pointer-events: none;">...</a> is not clickable at point (603, 217). Other element would receive the click: <div class="paginator-container">...</div>
         (Session info: headless chrome=98.0.4758.109)
     # 0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102e87960 chromedriver + 4438368
     # 1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102e1d03c chromedriver + 4001852
     # 2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a7230c chromedriver + 156428
     # 3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102aa73bc chromedriver + 373692
     # 4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102aa55e0 chromedriver + 366048
     # 5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102aa341c chromedriver + 357404
     # 6   chromedriver                        0x0000000102aa23cc chromedriver + 353228
     # 7   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a97c50 chromedriver + 310352
     # 8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102a97648 chromedriver + 308808
     # 9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102aca454 chromedriver + 517204
     # 10  chromedriver                        0x0000000102a96400 chromedriver + 304128
     # 11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e4a4a8 chromedriver + 4187304
     # 12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e60588 chromedriver + 4277640
     # 13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e65268 chromedriver + 4297320
     # 14  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e60dd0 chromedriver + 4279760
     # 15  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e402ec chromedriver + 4145900
     # 16  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e79f0c chromedriver + 4382476
     # 17  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e7a080 chromedriver + 4382848
     # 18  chromedriver                        0x0000000102e8e28c chromedriver + 4465292
     # 19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b54e9240 _pthread_start + 148
     # 20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b54e4024 thread_start + 8
     # ./spec/features/pagination_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.4'

gem 'react-rails'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]

  gem 'factory_bot_rails'

  gem 'lorem_ipsum_amet'

  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'codecov', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.5'
  gem 'database_cleaner-active_record'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

test suite (the examples marked xscenario pass):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Paginations", type: :feature do

  before(:all) do
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = true
  end

  after(:all) do
    ActionController::Base.allow_forgery_protection = false
  end

  xscenario "user visits articles home page to see only 10 articles", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 11)

    visit articles_path

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 10
  end

  xscenario "user clicks on prev button", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 11)

    visit articles_path

    click_link('next page')
    click_link('prev page')
   
    expect(Article.count).to eq(11)
    expect(page).to have_content(Article.last.title)
  end

  xscenario "user tries to click prev button on first page but button is disabled", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create(:article)

    visit articles_path

    expect(page).to have_link('prev page', style: 'pointer-events: none;')
  end

  scenario "user clicks on next button", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create(:article)

    visit articles_path

    click_link('next page')
    # save_and_open_page

    expect(page).to have_content(Article.first.title)
  end

  xscenario "user tries to click next button on last page but button is disabled", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 11)

    visit articles_path

    click_link('last page')

    expect(page).to have_link('next page', style: 'pointer-events: none;')
  end

  xscenario "user clicks on first page button", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 1)

    visit articles_path

    click_link('first page')

    expect(page).to have_content(Article.last.title)
  end


  xscenario "user clicks on last page button", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 15)

    visit articles_path

    click_link('last page')

    expect(page).to have_content(Article.first.title)
  end

  xscenario "user selects 5 for limit of items", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 6)

    visit articles_path

    select '5', from: 'paginator'

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 5
  end

  xscenario "user selects 10 for limit of items", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 11)

    visit articles_path

    select '10', from: 'paginator'

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 10
  end

  xscenario "user selects 25 for limit of items", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 26)

    visit articles_path

    select '25', from: 'paginator'

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 25
  end


  xscenario "user selects 50 for limit of items", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 51)

    visit articles_path

    select '50', from: 'paginator'

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 50
  end


  xscenario "user selects all for limit of items", js: true do
    FactoryBot.create_list(:article, 11)

    visit articles_path

    select 'all', from: 'paginator'

    expect(page).to have_css "h2.clickable-link", count: 11
  end
end
```

here is the pagination component (react):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import GetURLSearchParams from '../util/get-url-search-params';

const Paginator = (props) => {

    const { link, lastPage } = props;

    const { page, items_limit } = GetURLSearchParams(window.location);

    const itemsLimitParam = items_limit || 10;
    const pageNumber = page || 1;
    
    function submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        window.location.href = `${link}?page=1&items_limit=${e.target.value}`;
    }

  return (
    <div className="paginator-container">
        <a 
            className="paginator-btn"
            style={{"pointerEvents": itemsLimitParam !== 0 ? "auto" : "none"}}
            href={`${link}?page=1&items_limit=${itemsLimitParam}`}
        >
            first page
        </a>

        <a 
            className="paginator-btn paginator-btn-margin-left"
            style={{"pointerEvents": pageNumber > 1 ? "auto" : "none"}}
            href={`${link}?page=${pageNumber - 1}&items_limit=${itemsLimitParam}`}
        >
            prev page
        </a>

        <form onChange={submitHandler}>
            <select name="paginator">
                <option selected disabled>--Select limit of items--</option>
                <option value={0}>all</option>
                <option value={5}>5</option>
                <option value={10}>10</option>
                <option value={25}>25</option>
                <option value={50}>50</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <a 
            className="paginator-btn"
            style={{"pointerEvents": pageNumber < lastPage ? "auto" : "none"}}
            href={`${link}?page=${pageNumber + 1}&items_limit=${itemsLimitParam}`}
        >
            next page
        </a>
        
        <a 
            className="paginator-btn paginator-btn-margin-left"
            style={{"pointerEvents": itemsLimitParam !== 0 ? "auto" : "none"}}
            href={`${link}?page=${lastPage}&items_limit=${itemsLimitParam}`}
        >
            last page
        </a>
    </div>
  )
}

Paginator.propTypes = {
    link: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    lastPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}

export default Paginator
```

I have tried several ways to be more specific with querying the link but nothing I've tried works. Could it be a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1):

Most like this is because the window size being used by default in headless mode is too small and your layout is collapsing on itself.  You can try to check that by using `save_and_open_screenshot` to take an image of the page layout during your test. If that is the issue set the window size in your driver configuration, or use `current_window.resize_to(x, y)` at the start of your test, to whatever is necessary for your page to show normally